# Python data frame data analytics Group by nth column

Tags: python

I am working on a python data analytics.

first. this is the raw data

[image]

I want to get a result like

[image]

and My code is like

```
df_sellout.groupby("Brand")[:,0:4].sum()
```

But this doesn't work.

I want to use `[:,0:4]` because I have another massive data which I can't write all the columns name.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
df_sellout.groupby("Brand")[df_sellout.columns[2:].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put indexing by `iloc` in front of `groupby`:

```
df_sellout.iloc[:,0:4].groupby("Brand").sum()
```